# Where can I purchase Gunn diodes new?

Tags: diodes, microwave

Most electronic component retailers don't have these things. The only place I see them for sale is used Soviet-era Gunn diodes from the former USSR and Eastern Europe. I'm interested in getting one to use a low-power, high frequency oscillator. And I have read about GaN Gunn Diodes that have oscillating frequencies into the Terahertz range. Are the sale of Gunn diodes restricted because of their military applications? What interests me about them is their compact size and the fact that they will automatically start oscillating when a sufficient DC voltage is supplied and do not require any external passive components.

Comment: I don't think they're too restricted (that applies more to high power MMICs) but don't expect new ones to be cheap, I wouldn't be surprised is THz GUNN diodes cost as much as cars (most likely because they are custom made - and custom semiconductors *always* cost a fortune)

Comment: Sam, you're probably right.

Answer (score 2):

A number of domestic OEM sellers pop up in a brief search on the web. [Microsemi](http://www.microsemi.com/product-directory/rf-discretes/3305-diodes-gunn) has them, [MwT](http://www.mwtinc.com/cat/gunn_diodes/gunn_diodes.htm) has them, among others...No price info though.

Answer (score 1):

They used to be available relatively cheaply in the X band (10GHz) because they were used in doppler radar for motion detection etc.

I think that functionality has been replaced by microwave ICs and maybe even simpler circuits as used in toys, consumer radar guns etc.